# Using ModelCompanion's fromJSON method in Play application throws a NoSuchMethodException

Tags: json, scala, playframework, salat

I'm new to Scala and I'm trying to do my first Play 2.0 application. I'm using:

- Scala 2.9.3
- Play 2.0.4
- [SalatWithPlay2](https://github.com/novus/salat/wiki/SalatWithPlay2) 1.1

I have this in my `conf/routes` file:

```
PUT /newVenue   controllers.Application.createNewVenue
```

I have this in my `Application.scala` file:

```
def createNewVenue = Action(parse.json) { request =>
    val newVenue = Venue.fromJSON(request.body.toString)
    Venue.insert(newVenue)
    Ok("New Venue Created")
  }
```

And this is the code for `Venue.scala`:

```
import play.api.Play.current
import com.novus.salat._
import com.novus.salat.global._
import com.novus.salat.annotations._
import com.novus.salat.dao._
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
import se.radley.plugin.salat._

object Venue extends ModelCompanion[Venue, ObjectId] {
        val collection = mongoCollection("venues")
        val dao = new SalatDAO[Venue, ObjectId](collection = collection) {}
    }

case class Venue(
        @Key("_id") val venueId:ObjectId,
        var playlist:Playlist, 
        var isPlaying:Boolean = false)
```

To test if this is working I send a PUT request to `localhost:9000/newVenue` with this JSON as a body:

```
{"venueId": 3,"playlist":{"playlistId":2,"currentSongPosition":5},"isPlaying":false}
```

And then I get this **error**:

```
[error] application - 

! @6d7oco1hf - Internal server error, for request [PUT /newVenue] ->

play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[NoSuchMethodException: model.Venue$.apply$default$1()]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: model.Venue$.apply$default$1()
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater.defaultArg(Grater.scala:350) ~[salat-core_2.9.1-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater.safeDefault(Grater.scala:360) ~[salat-core_2.9.1-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(Grater.scala:319) ~[salat-core_2.9.1-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at com.novus.salat.ConcreteGrater$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(Grater.scala:319) ~[salat-core_2.9.1-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:218) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
```

I think the line triggering the error is **val newVenue = Venue.fromJSON(request.body.toString)**.

Does anyone have a clue of what's wrong?
I followed the tutorial in SalatWithPlay2 page and also followed some advices in [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987476/play-2-0-and-mongodb-interfacing-with-salat)), but I had no luck so far.

**UPDATE**:

I found a workaround, although it's not exactly a solution, but maybe it's helpful for somebody else and for understanding what is the actual solution.

If I remove the annotation @Key, the code of the case class Venue looks like this:

```
case class Venue(
        val venueId:ObjectId,
        var playlist:Playlist, 
        var isPlaying:Boolean = false)
```

And then I get this other error:

```
[RuntimeException: in: unexpected OID input class='net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$JInt', value='3']
```

And if instead of using ObjectId I use Long for example, the code looks like this:

```
case class Venue(
        val venueId:Long,
        var playlist:Playlist, 
        var isPlaying:Boolean = false)
```

And I get no error!

So the NoSuchMethodException apparently is related to the @Key annotation related to the _id. I also tried to rename venueId to _id and the same NoSuchMethodException error appeared. So the question is: **why can't I use the @Key annotation to say which of my attributes maps to the object id of the document in the mongo database?**
Besides that, regular Integers cannot be automatically converted to ObjectId instances for some other reason.

Thanks!

Comment: I found that another question with the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337473/brew-installed-scala-and-play-with-akka-throwing-an-exception), but no answer is given. This [other problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132730/play-framework-2-0-scala-classcastexception-models-mymodel-cannot-be-cast-to?rq=1) also looks very similar, but when trying to restart play nothing new happens, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found what was the problem.

The attributes of the Json sent in the body of the request must match the names of the attributes of the mongodb's document, not the attributes of the Scala object.

So if my class Venue is defined like this:
    case class Venue(
            @Key("_id") val venueId:ObjectId,
            var playlist:Playlist, 
            var isPlaying:Boolean = false)

The Json I have to send in the PUT request is:

```
{"_id": 3,"playlist":{"playlistId":2,"currentSongPosition":5},"isPlaying":false}
```

And **NOT**:

```
{"venueId": 3,"playlist":{"playlistId":2,"currentSongPosition":5},"isPlaying":false}
```

Comment: ahh That is because your using casbah! Sorry I did not think of that. I am so used to using Reactive Mongo, and you can map your objects via Reads, and Writes to what ever you want it to be. Basically you could leave your "venueId" and have the Reads map it to "_id".

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but can you try naming your object class to something else? Maybe to  VenueCompanion? It seems it is possible the compiler is getting confused on which object to apply to. IE it is not applying to the case class Venue, that you want. I am curious if the exception is still the same afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion and I get the exact same exception and stack trace :(